# alternative to grails multicolumn unique constraint (optimistic inserts)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a heavy used domain class `Relationship` which looks pretty similar to following one

```
class Relationship {
    Element source
    Element destination
    Type type

    // other properties omitted

    static constraints = {
         type unique: ['source', 'destination']
    }
}
```

I have a service creating new instances of this domain class which checks for existing instances and if found reuses them but I would like to implement sort of optimistic inserts with the unique constraint only in the database because

1. GORM unique constraints are highly inefficient (for a simple task I got 13 000 hits just checking the constraints and one third of the time spent)
2. finding the existing entity is expensive while running in batch (each query flushes the current session and costs about 40ms)

So the idea is to let the `save` method fail and than reuse the existing entity

```
try {
    relationshipInstance.save()
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException | ConstraintViolationException e) {
    // find and reuse
}
```

but than when I try to find the entity I got hibernate exception

```
AssertionFailure: null id in Relationship entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

1. Is there any way how to recover from the exception (`relationshipInstance.discard()` does not help as it does not have `EntityKey`)?
2. What other solution would you recommend for on demand uniqueness checking without triggering flush?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the validation when calling save, like this:

```
relationshipInstance.save(validate:false)
```

See [documentation for save method](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) for further info.

Comment: thanks, but that's probably not what I'm looking for. this will case the same problem as you can't disable the database constraints using this notation.

Comment: If you have really large amount of data that needs to be loaded to the database, I would recommend to use JDBC directly. Gorm/Hibernate performs quite poorly for large volumes. If you still want to use Gorm, it is better to create all objects in a structure outside a transaction and then save them all in one go within a transaction.