# use grails unique constraint only for generating DDL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to generate multicolumn unique constraints in Grails such as one defined in following entity class

```
class Relationship {
    Element source
    Element destination
    Type type

    // other properties omitted

    static constraints = {
         type unique: ['source', 'destination']
    }
}
```

but I don't want to have that constraint active during the validation as it consumes lot of resources (see [alternative to grails multicolumn unique constraint (optimistic inserts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148220/alternative-to-grails-multicolumn-unique-constraint-optimitic-inserts)) for stats.

Is there any way to achieve that? What are the alternatives to generate the unique index automatically (with checking for existing one)?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in an app where I knew that a column's values were unique based on how they were generated, so I didn't want Grails to run a select query during validation, but wanted the database check just in case something weird happened.

I would do this using a database migration. Add whatever constraints and indexes you like, in addition to the updates that are needed to keep the code and database in sync (e.g. adding/removing columns or tables, changing column types, etc.)

Comment: thanks Burt! do you know, is there a better way [to check the index is already present in the db](https://github.com/MetadataRegistry/ModelCataloguePlugin/blob/develop/ModelCatalogueCorePluginTestApp/grails-app/migrations/changelog_011_relationshipOptimization.groovy) than check it by name? if you done something similar, don't you have any hints for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148220/alternative-to-grails-multicolumn-unique-constraint-optimistic-inserts